# Querying Data from another firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So I'm trying to write a program that allows two different users to access certain pieces of eachother's data through some kind of "link" or some other method of accessing specific information in someone else's local database. For my experiments I am using two realtime databases with Firebase. Here is a sample of how their databases would look

```
User1
  | UserInfo
    |...
  | Friends
    | Friend1
      | Friend1Info
        | Birthdate etc...
```

I have no problem iterating through database entries and querying them, I just don't know how I would be able to log into my app as User1 and then query specific pieces of information from User2's local database. For example, User A wants to see a list of User B's friends, and their information. Before this, I have code that verifies whether or not User B has given User A access to their friend's list, so all that is left is finding a way to get that information from User B's database onto User A's screen so they can either store the information for themselves, or simply view it. User A cannot modify this data. Is this possible with firebase at all?

Comment: Have you looked at using [Firebase's Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)?

Comment: @HondaGuy Yes, I wasn't able to find any of the information I needed.

Comment: The chat example contains [security rule example code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-revisiting-advanced-example) that controls access to the member list of a chat room. There's similarity there with what I think you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Will the data be stored in two different databases or under different nodes in the same database?

Comment: @AndréKool The two user's data will be stored in their own respective databases.

Comment: Saying they *will be stored within their own respective databases* or *someone else's local database* is a little unclear. I think that @AndréKool was asking; will your data be stored in two different *project* databases or within a single project database. i.e. *MyGameApp/users/User1* and then *MyChatApp/users/User1* or are they both stored within the same project database as in *MyGroceryApp/users/User1* and *MyGroceryApp/users/User2*.

Comment: @Jay The different user's data will be stored in separate project databases

Comment: That's going to be pretty limiting and pretty tricky to make work as the Firebase user data would be stored in two completely different databases which cannot directly access each other. i.e. there's no 'link' between them per se. I would suggest looking for an alternate strategy where related users would be stored within the same database.